# Configuring the Google Identity Toolkit for PHP ambiguous installation locations in quickstart example

Tags: php, google-identity-toolkit

Following the google identity toolkit for php quickstart (in Windows), 
(https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/php), steps 1.9  and 2.1 are ambiguous.

Running Apache on :8000 (http//localhost:8000) with

- `c:\root\public` for documents
- `c:\root\key` for the p12 key directory
- `c:\root\php` for private php files

**Step 1.9:**

> change serviceAccountPrivateKeyFile setting to be equal to the path of
>   the *.p12 file you downloaded earlier. You should use the full path,
>   beginning with /and ending with the full name of the *.p12 file.

In windows, should this path look like either of:

```
 - "c:/root/key/key.p12"
 - "c:\root\key\key.p12"
 - "/root/key/key.p12"
```

**2.1**

> Download the Google Identity Toolkit PHP quick-start from GitHub and
>   unzip it. You can also find the source code for this quick-start or
>   the client library on Github.

This results in a folder:
`identity-toolkit-php-master` with yet another folder zipped within
`gitkit-php-composer-package.zip`. Which directory should these be unzipped to?

**2.3**

> Install the PHP dependency management tool Composer, and the dependent
>   libraries used by this quick-start. For Windows, installation
>   instructions are on the Composer website (use the composer.json
>   requirements file we included in the quickstart folder). For
>   Linux/Mac, simply run the following commands:
>
> cd identity-toolkit-php-master curl -s
>   https://getcomposer.org/installer | php php composer.phar install php
>   -S localhost:8000 routing.php

Installing from https//getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows, should any defaults be changed?

Answer (score 1):

The `serviceAccountPrivateKeyFile` setting will be read by php's `file_get_contents`. I think the absolute windows path should be fine:
`c:/root/key/key.p12`
I may be wrong about the direction of slashes used. If this doesn't work, just reverse the slashes.

Regarding where to place the contents of the client files identity-toolkit-php-client-master, it shouldn't matter but I would place it in a private directory with other library files. As for the composer step, I believe it will read the composer.json file in the unzipped `identity-toolkit-php-client-master` which specifies src include files relative to its current location, so I would install and run that in the same directory where the `composer.json` file is located: `identity-toolkit-php-client-master/`